How to mock const& methods with gmock
If I have:
class Foo
{
public:
virtual int Duplicate(int) const& = 0;
};

How can I define a mock object with gMock inheriting from Foo and mocking the Duplicate method?
I have tried:
class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, Duplicate, (int), (const&, override));
};

but it doesn't work, do you have any suggestions?

At least from v1.12.x, from gmock_cook_book, use ref(&), so
class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, Duplicate, (int), (const, ref(&), override));
};

Demo
For v1.10.0, there is still a workaround with indirection:
class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, DuplicateRef, (int), (const));
    int Duplicate(int n) const& override { return DuplicateRef(n); }
};

Demo

Thanks for the reply, I have tried and I get this error:
error: static assertion failed: ref(&) cannot be recognized as a valid specification modifier.

It compiles well https://godbolt.org/z/qdvdazMq1. Post a [mcve] that raises error: static assertion failed.

may I ask you which version of gtest you are using? I'm on 1.10

godbolt has only 2 versions, 1.10 which fails, and trunk which succeeds.

ok, so it's just my old bugged version. Thank you very much

I believe for the 1.10 version there is no way to achieve my purpose, am I right?

Added workaround for v.1.10.0
